# Sql query for combination two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Let say, I have two tables

Table 1:

```
code|name 
121  ab
456  qw
```

Table 2 :

```
Kode_ak|Nama_ak
 1      Bursa
 2      Kustodian
 3      Kliring
 4      Assurance
 5      Bunga
```

I want to combine those two tables. The result will be like this:

```
Kode_AK|Nama_ak    |code|name
 1      Bursa       121  ab
 2      Kustodian   121  ab
 3      Kliring     121  ab
 4      Assurance   121  ab
 5      Bunga       121  ab
 1      Bursa       456  qw
 2      Kustodian   456  qw
 3      Kliring     456  qw
 4      Assurance   456  qw
 5      Bunga       456  qw
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would do this using `cross join`:

```
select *
from table1 cross join
     table2;
```

Answer (score -1):

`select t3.Kode_AK,t3.Nama_ak,t1.code,t1.name from [dbo].[Table_1] t1 cross join [dbo].[Table_3] t3`

[image]